# Global AJAX Settings Not Firing on Custom Modal (DurandalJS)

Tags: jquery, ajax, durandal-2.0

I have DurandalJS Single Page Apps, 
all data is retrieved from API request and required header include **X-Auth-Token** to be set. 
Everything is works except when I call custom modal to display an iframe,

Below you can see how I setup global Ajax setting on main.js:

```
$(document)
.ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings)
{
    var token = getCookie('X-Auth-Token') || getSession('X-Auth-Token');

     if (token)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', token);
})
.ajaxError(function(event, xhr, settings){
    if (xhr.status === 401)
    {
        tokenExpired();
    }
});
```

And here is the code for the custom modal:

**customModal.js**

```
define(['plugins/dialog', /* etc */ ], function (dialog, /* etc */) {

    var iframeBox = function(id, title)
    {
        this.id         = id;
        this.title      = title;
    };

    iframeBox.prototype.ok = function()
    {
        dialog.close(this);
    };

    iframeBox.prototype.download = function()
    {
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/api/storages/" + this.id + "/download";
    };

    iframeBox.show = function(id, title)
    {
        return dialog.show(new iframeBox(id, title));
    };

    return iframeBox;
});
```

**customModal.html**

```
<div class="modal-content messageBox">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <button data-bind="click: download">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="td td-auto">
                <h5 data-bind="text: title"></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <iframe data-bind="attr: { src: 'http://example.com/api/storages/' + id + '/view' }">
    </iframe>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ok">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When custom modal is shown,
It also will make a request to `http://example.com/api/storages/{id}/view`

But it doesn't firing global `$.ajaxSend` that was set before.

Anyone please help.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem! Hoping for someone to be able to answer it... :)

Comment: You are setting the src of iframe that will make a synchronous GET request directly from browser and it will not send any ajax request. To make an ajax request, you have to explicitly call src url in ajax call. One workaround that you can try is make a data fetching call in customModal.js and add the iframe HTML in CustomModal.html and bind it. Let me know if you have some other requirement or in case you want it in code.

Comment: Hi @khagesh, Thanks for reply ! Would appreciate if you can post some code for example to explain what has been described.

Comment: If possible, can post `$.ajax()` call pieces ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that request is not cross domain and assuming that data returned from dynamically generated URL is JSON. Even if assumption does not hold you can just change the type of ajax request with other settings and it should work.

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khagesh17/3qb8X/3/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ajaxIframe = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var src = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        // we may use $.load if that fits your purpose of binding html inside iframe
        // i am not aware if you are returning html or json from that url
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    'a': '1',
                    'b': '2',
                    'c': '3',
                    'd': '4'
                }),
                delay: 3 
            },
            beforeSend: function(jqXhr) {
                 // here as well you can hook to add header to this request
            }
            success: function(data) {
                // now we have got the data
                // insert the data inside the iframe
                var iFrameDocument = element.contentDocument.body;
                if (iFrameDocument) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    //just dump all data inside iframe
                    span.innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
                    iFrameDocument.appendChild(span);
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Also in view the binding should be updated to use above custom binding.

```
<iframe data-bind="ajaxIframe: source"></iframe>
```

Also, on side note if you want to send custom header with each and every request. You might do this as well

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'x-custom-header': 'value' }
});
```